# DataFrame セル内の記号を消したい

Tags: python, pandas

気温データをDFに取り込んだところ、「11月」と「年の値」のコラムに「 ] 」が含まれた数値があります。
この記号を削除したいのですが、どうすればいいでしょうか。

データタイプは、

Miyagi_temp['年の値'].unique().tolist()

で確認して記号付きはstrになっています。

Miyagi_temp['年の値'].str.strip(' ]')　
を実行すると記号は消えますが、記号付きの数値以外はすべてnanになってしまいます。

Miyagi_temp['年の値'].str.replace(' ]', '')
を実行しても同じ結果です。

すいませんがよろしくお願いします。

[image: 気温データ]

Comment: ここのデータでしょうか。[仙台　日平均気温の月平均値（℃）](http://www.data.jma.go.jp/obd/stats/etrn/view/monthly_s3.php?prec_no=34&block_no=47590&year=&month=&day=&elm=monthly&view=a1) ちなみにもう一個、2011年3月のデータの後ろに ` \)` が付いていますね。

Comment: ありがとうございます。問題解決しました。

Comment: 問題解決されたようなので質問を閉じましょう。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

記号の削除と dtype を変更します。

```py
# object type の列名を抽出
cols = Miyagi_temp.select_dtypes('O').columns

# 数字と負号("-")と "." 以外を削除して dtype を object から float64 へ変更
Miyagi_temp[cols] = (
  Miyagi_temp[cols].replace(r'[^\d.-]', '', regex=True).astype('float64'))

pd.set_option('display.unicode.east_asian_width', True)
print(Miyagi_temp.dtypes)

#
年          int64
1月       float64
2月       float64
3月       float64
4月       float64
5月       float64
6月       float64
7月       float64
8月       float64
9月       float64
10月      float64
11月      float64
12月      float64
年の値    float64

print(Miyagi_temp.head().to_string(index=False))

  年  1月  2月  3月  4月  5月  6月  7月  8月  9月  10月  11月  12月  年の値
1926  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  11.8   6.8   1.7     6.8
1927 -0.6 -1.5  2.5  9.0 13.6 17.6 23.4 24.2 18.5  13.9   8.3   2.1    10.9
1928  0.4  0.1  2.9  8.8 13.7 16.9 21.1 22.4 21.6  14.2   8.8   1.4    11.0
1929 -1.3 -0.7  2.9  8.7 12.9 16.7 23.3 24.9 18.7  14.3   8.2   5.0    11.1
1930 -0.6  1.9  5.6  9.9 14.4 18.4 22.4 24.5 19.2  13.9   6.8   2.3    11.6

print(Miyagi_temp.tail().to_string(index=False))

  年  1月  2月  3月  4月  5月  6月  7月  8月  9月  10月  11月  12月  年の値
2017  2.5  3.2  5.4 11.5 17.0 18.6 25.1 23.0 21.1  14.9   9.1   3.5    12.9
2018  1.4  1.4  7.5 12.5 17.0 20.3 25.5 24.9 20.8  16.5  10.7   4.3    13.6
2019  2.4  3.7  7.0 10.2 17.4 19.0 22.4 26.2 22.4  16.9  10.0   5.4    13.6
2020  4.0  4.4  7.5 10.1 16.8 21.2 21.3 26.6 22.5  15.6  10.8   3.9    13.7
2021  1.2  3.7  8.6 11.6 17.0 20.6 24.1 24.9 20.8  15.8  15.1   NaN    14.8
```